# NDSolve will try solving the system as differential-algebraic equations but it didn't get the solution

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, warning-messages, piecewise

Please help me deal with this kind of question about ODEs.
My codes are as follows

```
m = 100;
a = D[x[t], {t, 2}];
t1up = 2 x''[t] + 1/2 (490 + 34 x''[t] + 2 (490 + 50 x''[t]));
t1down = 490 + 53 x''[t];
t1 = Piecewise[{{t1up, x'[t] >= 0}, {t1down, x'[t] < 0}}]
equa00 = t1 == m*a
t0 = 50;
s1 = NDSolve[{equa00, x[0] == 1, x'[0] == 1}, x, {t, 0, 50}]
```

However, I get an error:

> NDSolve::ntdvdae: Cannot solve to find an explicit formula for the derivatives. NDSolve will try solving the system as differential-algebraic equations. >>

So is it a differential-algebraic equation? How to solve it?

I have another question, too: How to plot the `t1-t` figure after we get the `s1`?
I have tried the following codes:

```
t1upvalue = (t1up /. {x'[t] -> (x'[t] /. s1), x''[t] -> (x''[t] /. s1)})
t1downvalue = (t1down /. {x'[t] -> (x'[t] /. s1), x''[t] -> (x''[t] /. s1)})
t1value = Piecewise[{{t1upvalue, (x'[t] /. s1) >= 0}, {t1downvalue, (x'[t] /. s1) < 0}}],
Plot[t1value[[1]], {t, 0, t0},PlotRange -> All]
```

However it doesn't work.

Comment: Which version are you in? In _v12_ and _v11.3_ I get the `ndnum` warning.

Comment: my answer is is in version 7.

Comment: Does `Solve[equa00, x''[t]]` work in V7? Does the `"EventLocator"`method for `NDSolve` work in V7?

Comment: @Michael E2，what do you mean ,i have never used `Solve` and `EventLocator`

Comment: this question has been solved but there are some question related https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/209122/nintegrate-failed-to-converge-and-why

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Another solution is to use [`` Simplify`PWToUnitStep ``](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/133530/1871):

```
s1 = NDSolve[{equa00 // Simplify`PWToUnitStep, x[0] == 1, x'[0] == 1}, x, {t, 0, 50}]
```

Comment: it runs successfully in verson 7 and thanks a lot!

Answer (score 6):

Changing the last line to:

```
s1 = NDSolve[{equa00, x[0] == 1, x'[0] == 1}, x, {t, 0, 50}, SolveDelayed -> True]
```

or

```
s1 = NDSolve[{equa00, x[0] == 1, x'[0] == 1}, x, {t, 0, 50}, 
  Method -> {"EquationSimplification" -> "Residual"}]
```

seems help for your problem.

**In reponse to updated question on plot slution**

To plot your solution, maybe this is what you want?

```
Remove["Global`*"] // Quiet;
m = 100;
a = D[x[t], {t, 2}];
t1up = 2 x''[t] + 1/2 (490 + 34 x''[t] + 2 (490 + 50 x''[t]));
t1down = 490 + 53 x''[t];
t1 = Piecewise[{{t1up, x'[t] >= 0}, {t1down, x'[t] < 0}}];
equa00 = t1 == m*a;
t0 = 50;
(*s1 = NDSolveValue[{equa00 // Simplify`PWToUnitStep, x[0] == 1, 
    x'[0] == 1}, x, {t, 0, 50}];*)
s1 = x /.First@NDSolve[{equa00 // Simplify`PWToUnitStep, x[0] == 1, 
 x'[0] == 1}, x, {t, 0, 50}];
sAll = {x[t] -> s1[t], x'[t] -> s1'[t], x''[t] -> s1''[t]};

t1upvalue = t1up /. sAll;
t1downvalue = t1down /. sAll;
t1value = 
 Piecewise[{{t1upvalue, s1'[t] >= 0}, {t1downvalue, s1'[t] < 0}}];
Plot[t1value, {t, 0, t0}, PlotRange -> All]
```

Comment: the `SolveDelayed -> True` can help but the  `Method -> {"EquationSimplification" -> "Residual"}` can't in version 7 with tips `NDSolve::bdmtd: The value of the option Method -> {EquationSimplification->Residual} is not a known built-in method, a symbol that could be a user-defined method, or a list with a name followed by method options. >>`

Comment: @dcydhb IIRC `"EquationSimplification" -> "Residual"` is introduced in _v9_.

Comment: thanks for your Supplement but because there is no `NDSolveValue` in version 7and i use the `First@NDSolve`  instead HOWEVER it doesn't ,so is there a way that i can use it version 7

Comment: I updated the code. After `First@NDSolve`, you can then  use `Replace` (`/.`) to make `s1` a pure function.

Comment: i don't konw how to use @, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Here is the sort of thing I meant in [my comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/209044/ndsolve-will-try-solving-the-system-as-differential-algebraic-equations-but-it-d/209135#comment536432_209044):

*1. Get a single piecewise function*

```
constraint = equa00 /. Equal -> Subtract // PiecewiseExpand
```

[image]

*2. Solve each piece for `x''[t]`*

```
solvexpp = x''[t] /. First@Solve[# == 0, x''[t]] &;
newode = x''[t] == MapAt[solvexpp, constraint, {{-1}, {1, 1, 1}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

A `PiecewiseFunction` can have more pieces. You can add the part indices to the list `{{-1}, {1, 1, 1}}`.  `MapAt` was updated in V10 to allow the following to handle arbitrarily many pieces. (I don't think this works in earlier versions, but remembering so far back is not reliable.)

```
newode = x''[t] == MapAt[solvexpp, constraint, {{-1}, {1, All, 1}}]
```

If `MapAt` doesn't work in V7, try `ReplacePart`:

```
newode = x''[t] == ReplacePart[constraint, {
    {-1} -> solvexpp[constraint[[-1]]],
    {1, 1, 1} -> solvexpp[constraint[[1, 1, 1]]]}]
```

*3. Integrate*

```
s1 = NDSolve[{newode, x[0] == 1, x'[0] == 1}, x, {t, 0, 50}]
```

[image]