# NIntegrate failed to converge and why?

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration

i have put up and question about the `NDSolve` and have got the solution of the ODE,and also got the figure of `t1-t` ,however when i use the solution of the `t1-t` to integrate ,the integral didn't converge and the figure of the `p1` is continous but when i export the `p1` result to the EXCEL,the figure is Discontinuous,so how to deal with it?

the related questions

[NDSolve will try solving the system as differential-algebraic equations but it didn't get the solution](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/209044/ndsolve-will-try-solving-the-system-as-differential-algebraic-equations-but-it-d)

and i have Extract the equation of the original question and

codes are as this

```
equa00 = 0.` - \[Piecewise] {
  {2 x''[t] + 1/2 (4900.` + 259 x''[t] + 2 (4900.` + 500 x''[t])),
    x'[t] >= 0},
  {4900.` + 503 x''[t], x'[t] < 0},
  {0, \!\(\*
     TagBox["True",
      "PiecewiseDefault",
      AutoDelete->False,
      DeletionWarning->True]\)}
 } + 159715.5` (0.25` Cos[1.7951958020513104` t] - x[t]) - 
13130.602263408473` Cos[
  1.7951958020513104` t] (0.613591041570793` + 
   0.25` Cos[1.7951958020513104` t] - x[t]) + 
6519.` Abs[-0.4487989505128276` Sin[1.7951958020513104` t] - 
   x'[t]] (-0.4487989505128276` Sin[1.7951958020513104` t] - 
   x'[t]) + 16297.5` (\[Piecewise] {
    {0.56796693652872623432387422799011`31.754323054547157, 
     x'[t] >= 0},
    {0.49855266876742266072254490600473`31.69771104538948, 
     x'[t] < 0},
    {0, \!\(\*
       TagBox["True",
        "PiecewiseDefault",
        AutoDelete->False,
        DeletionWarning->True]\)}
   }) (0.613591041570793` + 0.25` Cos[1.7951958020513104` t] - 
   x[t]) (-0.8056819919256618` Cos[1.7951958020513104` t] - 
   x''[t]) == 10000 x''[t];


t1 = \[Piecewise] {
{2 x''[t] + 1/2 (4900 + 259 x''[t] + 2 (4900 + 500 x''[t])), 
 x'[t] >= 0},
{4900 + 503 x''[t], x'[t] < 0},
{0, \!\(\*
   TagBox["True",
    "PiecewiseDefault",
    AutoDelete->False,
    DeletionWarning->True]\)}
   };

t0 = 100;
s1 = NDSolve[{equa00, x[0] == 1, x'[0] == 1}, x, {t, 0, t0}, 
  SolveDelayed -> True]

p1 = (t1 /. s1)*(x[t] /. s1);
Plot[p1, {t, 0, t0}, PlotRange -> All]

period = 23.14;

paverage = NIntegrate[p1, {t, 40, 40 + period}]/period
```

i just want to integrate the `p1`,however it doesn't converge

```
NIntegrate::slwcon: Numerical integration converging too slowly; suspect one of the following: singularity, value of the integration is 0, highly oscillatory integrand, or WorkingPrecision too small. >>
NIntegrate::ncvb: NIntegrate failed to converge to prescribed accuracy after 9 recursive bisections in t near {t} = {43.7509}. NIntegrate obtained -7211.41 and 23.400613386693852` for the integral and error estimates. >>
```

the result is

```
{-311.643}
```

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE, dcydhb! I suggest the following: 
1) Take the [tour](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS).   
2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by clicking the gray triangles, because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by clicking the checkmark sign! 
3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Comment: @Chris K,in fact when there are more than 2 answers and they all can solve my questions,i don't konw how to select and in fact i want to select them all.

Comment: Yeah that can be hard to decide.  In any case, there is no limit to the number of answers that you can upvote with the gray triangle.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply increasing the `MaxRecursion` gives an answer without the `NIntegrate::ncvb` message:

```
paverage = 
 NIntegrate[p1, {t, 40, 40 + period}, MaxRecursion -> 100]/period
(* {-311.506} *)
```

BTW, looking at your function over this range, it does not look like the period is `23.14`.

```
Plot[p1, {t, 40, 40 + period}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**EDIT:** Extra method

@MichaelE2's answer is so nice it motivates me to improve mine a little.  So here's an alternative, `NIntegrate`-free approach, that solves for the integral within the `NDSolve`:

```
s1 = NDSolve[{equa00, intp1'[t] == t1*x[t], x[0] == 1, x'[0] == 1,
  intp1[0] == 0}, {x, intp1}, {t, 0, t0}, SolveDelayed -> True]

(intp1[40 + period] - intp1[40])/period /. s1[[1]]
(* -311.513 *)
```

Comment: yes,the real period is not `23.14`,it doesn't matter this question,and `NIntegrate::slwcon: Numerical integration converging too slowly; suspect one of the following: singularity, value of the integration is 0, highly oscillatory integrand, or WorkingPrecision too small. >>` still exist,it means the result is not accurate or it only means the Convergence is slow ?

Comment: and if the real solution of `p1` is continous,will the figure of `p1` is continous means the solution of `p1` is continus? why when i export `p1` data to EXCEL and plot in EXCEL,the figure is discontinous?

Comment: [NIntegrate::slwcon](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/message/NIntegrate/slwcon.html) is a warning, not an error.  If you get an answer without `NIntegrate::ncvb` it should be good.  Sorry, I have no idea about your plot in Excel.

Comment: you have solved my question and thanks a lot!

Comment: @dcydhb I believe `p1` is discontinuous when `x'[t] == 0`. `Plot` cannot figure that out on its own.  Compare with `Plot[p1, {t, 40, 44}, PlotRange -> All, 
 Exclusions -> (x'[t] == 0 /. First@s1)]`.

Answer (score 5):

An `InterpolatingFunction` has weak singularities at each point of the interpolating grid. They confound the default integration rules, which are a based on the assumption that the integrand is smooth. You can specify the singularities sometimes with `Method -> "InterpolationPointsSubdivision"`, but it does not work here, maybe because of the complexity of `p1`.  You can also list them explicitly in the iterator that specifies the domain of integration.

```
sing = Flatten[x["Grid"] /. s1]; (* the interpolation grid *)

With[{iter =  (* add the relevant singularities to the iterator *)
   Flatten@{t, 40, Select[sing, 40 < # < 40 + period &], 40 + period}},
 paverage = NIntegrate[p1, iter]/period
 ]
(*  {-311.513}  *)
```

---

*Update*

OK, currently this answer has more upvotes than @ChrisK's.  While that answer does not explain why it works, Chris's approach does handle the integral more effectively than my way above.  I can explain why.

There are two sources of truncation error in the numerical integration. One comes from the weak singularities that mentioned above.  Another, that I mentioned only in a comment, comes from discontinuities in `p1` at the points where `x'[t] == 0`.  Further investigation shows these are more significant than the weak singularities I mentioned (and there are 6000+ of them).  The setting `MaxRecursion -> 100` may seem overkill, but it allows `NIntegrate` to resolve (quickly, in fact) the error at the discontinuities.  The error from the weak singularities does not matter that much because the interpolation grid is so fine that those errors are not that great.

Here's how to see what is going on in Chris's solution:

```
Needs["Integration`NIntegrateUtilities`"]

Show[
 NIntegrateSamplingPoints@
  NIntegrate[p1, {t, 40, 40 + period}, MaxRecursion -> 100],
 Plot[5000 x'[t] /. s1, {t, 40, 40 + period}, PlotStyle -> Red],
 PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

We can see that the sampling is concentrated along the lines where `x'[t] == 0`.  Every now and then the intervals between these roots are subdivided and resampled.  This happens when the error from the discontinuities becomes less than the error from the weak singularities (this is the global adaptive strategy).  If we do the same analysis on my code, we see that there is very little recursive subdivision with about 50% more sampling points -- and it takes ten times as long.  That time can be cut in half with `Method -> {"GlobalAdaptive", "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0}`.

```
Show[
 With[{iter = 
    Flatten@{t, 40, Select[sing, 40 < # < 40 + period &], 40 + period}},
  NIntegrateSamplingPoints@NIntegrate[p1, iter]
  ],
 Plot[5000 x'[t] /. s1, {t, 40, 40 + period}, PlotStyle -> Red],
 PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]